# Creating a custom User model by extending AbstractBaseUser

Tags: python-3.x, django

I am trying to create a custom User(CustomUser) by extending AbstractBaseUser. I am trying to remove username field and use email for authentication.I have not done the first migration yet. Here is models.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser
from django.contrib.auth.models import PermissionsMixin
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _

from .managers import UserManager


class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    """
    An abstract base class implementing a fully featured User model with
    admin-compliant permissions.
    email and password are required. Other fields are optional.
    """

    first_name = models.CharField(_("first name"), max_length=150, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(_("last name"), max_length=150, blank=True)
    email = models.EmailField(_("email address"), unique=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(
        _("staff status"),
        default=False,
        help_text=_("Designates whether the user can log into this admin site."),
    )
    is_active = models.BooleanField(
        _("active"),
        default=True,
        help_text=_(
            "Designates whether this user should be treated as active. "
            "Unselect this instead of deleting accounts."
        ),
    )
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(_("date joined"), default=timezone.now)

    objects = UserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = "email"
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ["email"]

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _("user")
        verbose_name_plural = _("users")
        abstract = True

    def clean(self):
        super().clean()
        self.email = self.__class__.objects.normalize_email(self.email)

    def get_full_name(self):
        """
        Return the first_name plus the last_name, with a space in between.
        """
        full_name = "%s %s" % (self.first_name, self.last_name)
        return full_name.strip()

    def get_short_name(self):
        """Return the short name for the user."""
        return self.first_name

    def email_user(self, subject, message, from_email=None, **kwargs):
        """Send an email to this user."""
        send_mail(subject, message, from_email, [self.email], **kwargs)
```

and below is managers.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.base_user import BaseUserManager
from django.contrib.auth.hashers import make_password
from django.contrib import auth


class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    use_in_migrations = True

    def _create_user(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        """
        Create and save a user with the given email, and password.
        """
        if not email:
            raise ValueError("The given email must be set")
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        # Lookup the real model class from the global app registry so this
        # manager method can be used in migrations. This is fine because
        # managers are by definition working on the real model.
        user = self.model(email=email, **extra_fields)
        user.password = make_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_user(self, email=None, password=None, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault("is_staff", False)
        extra_fields.setdefault("is_superuser", False)
        return self._create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)

    def create_superuser(self, email=None, password=None, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault("is_staff", True)
        extra_fields.setdefault("is_superuser", True)

        if extra_fields.get("is_staff") is not True:
            raise ValueError("Superuser must have is_staff=True.")
        if extra_fields.get("is_superuser") is not True:
           raise ValueError("Superuser must have is_superuser=True.")

        return self._create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)

    def with_perm(
            self, perm, is_active=True, include_superusers=True, backend=None, 
 obj=None
    ):
        if backend is None:
            backends = auth._get_backends(return_tuples=True)
            if len(backends) == 1:
                backend, _ = backends[0]
            else:
                raise ValueError(
                    "You have multiple authentication backends configured and "
                    "therefore must provide the `backend` argument."
                )
        elif not isinstance(backend, str):
            raise TypeError(
                "backend must be a dotted import path string (got %r)." % backend
           )
        else:
            backend = auth.load_backend(backend)
         if hasattr(backend, "with_perm"):
            return backend.with_perm(
               perm,
                is_active=is_active,
                include_superusers=include_superusers,
                obj=obj,
            )
        return self.none()
```

in settings.py below installed apps and middlewares

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'shop.CustomUser'
```

However, i am getting the below error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File 
        N85WgZsI/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/admin.py", line 6, 
in <module>
from django.contrib.auth.forms import (
  File "/Users/ankurshrivastava/.local/share/virtualenvs/ankurshrivastava- 
N85WgZsI/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/forms.py", line 21, in 
<module>
    UserModel = get_user_model()
  File "/Users/ankurshrivastava/.local/share/virtualenvs/ankurshrivastava- 
  N85WgZsI/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/__init__.py", line 164, in 
    get_user_model
    raise ImproperlyConfigured(
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: AUTH_USER_MODEL refers to model 
'shop.CustomUser' that has not been installed
```

What am i doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2):

This happens because you are making this model as an abstract model `abstract = True` and Django won't create a database table for it, so delete it from `Meta` class, and will work fine.

Comment: Great! Thank you. It worked.That was me being lousy, silly mistake.